# Install Visual Studio 2015 extension on 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

Recently, my team has upgraded to Visual Studio 2017 from 2015. It's been great so far (even disabled ReSharper to see how it goes), but I'm just missing one thing.

[This](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ziyasal.AttachTo-Next) extension that makes it possible to attach the debugger with a single click or hotkey. The extension only is available for 2015, but is there a way to force-install it on 2017? I've tried Googling but couldn't find any results.

*Yes, I know VS2017 has an option to re-attach to the last process, but in my case there are multiple w3wp.exe processes and attaching to the right one is a hassle.*

Comment: Have you tried https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErlandR.ReAttach

Comment: No, but it seems that this is a re-attach extension. It's kind of like re-attach to last process of VS2017 and I don't want that.

Comment: AttachTo is open sourced. Have you tried to build it from VS 2017 with newer extension SDK and then submit a pull request?

Answer (score 2):

An extension created for VS 2015 uses assemblies that are available on VS 2017, either directly or through binding redirects of devenv.exe.config on folder Common7\IDE of VS 2017, so that part is not a problem. The opposite, to make an extension created for VS 2017 to run on VS 2015 would be more problematic.

The problem for VS 2017 comes from the new contents of the VSIX file (a VSIX file is actually a .zip file so you can rename it to .zip for inspection):

- Two new .json files (catalog.json and manifest.json)
- A extension.vsixmanifest that uses "version 3" instead of "version 2". Everything is the same than in "version 2" (included the version 2.0.0.0) but it needs a new  section that must declare at least a prerequisite of the core editor of VS 2017:

<Prerequisites>

<Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[15.0,16.0)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" />

</Prerequisites>

To create all that by hand can be done, but the easiest way would be to build the source code on VS 2017 with the latest VSSDK 15.x NuGet package.

See my post [It’s time to change the VSIX manifest of your extension to v3 for Visual Studio 2017 compatibility](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2017/01/10/its-time-to-change-the-vsix-manifest-of-your-extension-to-v3-for-visual-studio-2017-compatibility/)

Comment: I'm not using VSIX and put pkgdef and vsixmanifest to specific folders using installer (support early VS and SSMS). I created asyncPackage, modified vsixmanifest - add "Prerequisites", generated json files using code from [here](https://github.com/axodox/VsixUpdater). But after all VisualStudio mark extension as deprecated. Do you know what MS check to decide deprecated this extension or not?